# Google Sheets uniquecount function

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Is it expected or is there a reason that Google Sheets uniquecount returns one more than the actual unique count for a column?

Comment: what formula you use and how your data table looks like - share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I would love to upload the spreadsheet, but I can not find how to do that on this site.  meh

Comment: just paste the link and set sharing to: view

Answer (score 0):

- could be the blank cell. you can always do **`-1`** or use:

  ```
  =COUNTUNIQUE(A1:A)
  ```

  [image]